# ManyToOne OneToMany bi-direction: Retrieve data from reference table

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I would like to while post an object, to return the data from the reference table of the relationship.

The relationship is defined as follow:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "application")
public class Application {

    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_category")
    private ProductCategory productCategory;

    ...

}
```

And:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_category")
public class ProductCategory {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "product_category_id")
    private Long productCategoryId;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "productCategory")
    private Set<Application> applications;

    ...
}
```

My product_category table has the following data:

[image]

While posting my Json object with the following structure:

```
...
{
  "productCategory": "0"
}
...
```

I would like to get the following json output:

```
...
"productCategory": {
    "productCategoryId": 0,
    "description": "Personal Loan"
},
...
```

But instead I'm getting:

```
...
"productCategory": {
    "productCategoryId": 0,
    "description": null
},
...
```

Can you please advise?

Comment: Can you post the code, that generates the json response?

Comment: It's just a simple a return of the repository. return applicationRepository.save(appRequest);

Comment: nothing can be said without seeing your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much code in your question, but you mentioned in your comment, what you are returning:

```
return applicationRepository.save(appRequest);
```

On the other hand, you are not cascading changes from parent to children in your mapping:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "product_category")
private ProductCategory productCategory;
```

I think changing `@ManyToOne` to `@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)` should help.

Edit:

If you cannot change the model, simply return your entity:

```
return applicationRepository.findById(id);
```

This way jpa won't overwrite the entity on saving, it simply reads one from db.

Comment: The data is already present on the product_category table. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but if I don't want to propagate the changes to the reference table, I don't need to use that option.

Comment: `save` method from `CrudRepository` returns persisted / merged entity. Maybe the data view in db is not refreshed. Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: I cannot use it in this case. product_category has a required description field which is not provided by this json object... so I cannot post the id only as it returns an error for null description field

Comment: how about using `return applicationRepository.findById(id)`?

Comment: It works if I search an entity! Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I thought that the save (although of course description is not part of it) would do a get in the end returning the posted object ... which would automatically retrieve the full object.

Comment: I have edited the answer with explanation, hope it helps.